# How does a For next/ loop in C actually evaluate the parameters?

Tags: c

This query came about as I was trying to test a port on a PIC18F45K42 in MPLAB.

It cncerns the way that the value of the variable is evaluated in a for next loop in c

If I use this:

```
 for di = 0 ; di = 10, di++
 {
 LATB = ~(LATB);
 __delay_ms(100);
 }
```

It enteres an endless loop with portB flashing forever.

If I change the variable to di < 9 it works as expected

```
 for di = 0 ; di <9, di++
 {
 LATB = ~(LATB);
 __delay_ms(100);
 }
```

If I change the variable to di >8 it skips the loop

```
for di = 0 ; di <9, di++
{
LATB = ~(LATB);
__delay_ms(100);
}
```

I thought that as long as the end condition could be evaluated it would work.

I am just curious as to how the end condition is evaluated and why only <n works.
It compiles fine every way (in MPLAB x ide)

Comment: You have a typo in the first loop, `di = 10` should be `di != 10`

Comment: As for the third loop (which you didn't copy-paste correctly), if `di` is initialized to `0`, then `di > 8` will be false and the loop will not iterate.

Comment: Oh and please make sure that *all* your code is copy-pasted correctly. None of the loops you show are valid C statements.

Comment: The code does not use the C language.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question

> How does a For next/ loop in C actually evaluate the parameters?

it could easily be translated to an equivalent `while` loop.

Take for example

```
for (di = 0 ; di != 10, di++)
{
    LATB = ~(LATB);
    __delay_ms(100);
}
```

<sub>[Note that I have corrected your loop]</sub>

This corresponds to the following `while` loop:

```
{
    di = 0;
    while (di != 10)
    {
        {
            LATB = ~(LATB);
            __delay_ms(100);
        }
        di++;
    }
}
```